# Dynamically allocate many small pieces of memory

Tags: c++, c, memory-management

I think this is a very common problem. Let me give an example.

I have a file, which contains many many lines (e.g. one million lines), and each line is of the following form: first comes a number `X`, and then follows a string of length `X`.

Now I want to read the file and store all the strings (for whatever reason). Usually, what I will do is: for every line I read the length `X`, and use `malloc` (in C) or `new` (in C++) to allocate `X` bytes, and then read the string.

The reason that I don't like this method: it might happen that most of the strings are very short, say under 8 bytes. In that case, according to my understanding, the allocation will be very wasteful, both in time and in space.

(First question here: am I understanding correctly, that allocating small pieces of memory is wasteful?)

I have thought about the following optimization: everytime I allocate a big chunk, say 1024 bytes, and whenever a small piece is needed, just cut it from the big chunk. The problem with this method is that, deallocation becomes almost impossible...

It might sound like I want to do the memory management myself... but still, I would like to know if there exists a better method? If needed, I don't mind use some data structure to do the management.

If you have some good idea that only works conditionally (e.g. with the knowledge that most pieces are small), I will also be happy to know it.

Comment: "I think this is a very common problem." – **Yesss!** Exactly. A common solution is using a memory pool – approximately the same thing that you described by pre-allocating a big chunk.

Comment: why do you need to dynamically allocate each new string from the file? like what the guy above me said though, you could allocate a large buffer to read the string into as opposed to many single allocations

Comment: The problem is that I will not be able to free the memory if I allocate them using a memory pool. That can be a big problem, right?

Comment: Memory pools are an option of course.  However, mostly implementations of `std::string` have a "small string optimization" where strings less than a certain length do not require dynamic allocation at all.  Given that you want to read "strings" from a file, I can't think of any good reason not to use `std::string`.

Comment: C or C++? Decent memory management is **completely** different between the two.

Comment: How are you planning on storing those strings? This sounds like a good case for std::vector<std::string>, with the vector holding everything together in a nice contiguous block.

Comment: @Chad Could you (or someone else) explain briefly how `std::string` does the "small string optimization"? This sounds interesting to me.

Comment: Basically the members of `std::string` that are necessary (pointer to data, length) are inside a `union` with a small character array (usually ~15 bytes), and a flag determines which part of the union is valid.  Of the length is less than the internal buffer, the data is stored directly in that buffer.

Comment: You can simply read the entire file to a single buffer that can fit it, and then separate the lines with a null-terminator `\0`, while keeping track of the address each line begins at in a separate array of `char*`, and thats it, you have all strings in memory with basically a single `malloc()`.

Comment: OK, I think with explanation of @Chad and the answer of Steve Jessop I am now able to figure out what to do with small pieces. Thanks everyone!

Comment: @WhatsUp "I will not be able to free the memory if I allocate them using a memory pool" – o.O What?

Comment: @The Paramagnetic Croissant Why? Am I saying something stupid?Maybe I should study memory pools in detail...

Comment: @WhatsUp Why couldn't you free memory that was allocated for a memory pool? You allocate the pool using the same facilities you would normally use, e.g. `malloc()` in C…

Comment: @The Paramagnetic Croissant What I mean is that, I cannot free the pool unless every piece in the pool is ready for free...

Comment: @WhatsUp that's correct, but it's not much of a problem. You are going to have an average (nonzero) amount of simultaneously-allocated objects anyway – along with some compacting, you can do pretty well.

Comment: 'I have thought about the following optimization' -- DON'T.  Until you have measured that something is a performance bottleneck, you are better off just writing simple clear code.  *IF* it turns out to be a performance problem, that is the time to look at how you can optimize it.

Comment: You don't _need_ any more memory than the longest string you can have + the size of the "number of unspecified format". So you just read x then that many bytes.  If you have enough memory, just mmap it and do the same on the whole data set.  You'd have to do this at least once anyhow to index it...  You may find that indexing them is not useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "natural" way to do memory allocation is to ensure that every memory block is at least big enough to contain a pointer and a size, or some similar book-keeping that's sufficient to maintain a structure of free nodes. The details vary, but you can observe the overhead experimentally by looking at the actual addresses you get back from your allocator when you make small allocations.

This is the sense in which small allocations are "wasty". Actually with most C or C++ implementations *all* blocks get rounded to a multiple of some power of 2 (the power depending on the allocator and sometimes on the order of magnitude size of the allocation). So all allocations are wasty, but proportionally speaking there's more waste if a lot of 1 and 2 byte allocations are padded out to 16 bytes, than if a lot of 113 and 114 byte allocations are padded out to 128 bytes.

If you're willing to do away with the ability to free and reuse just a single allocation (which is fine for example if you're planning to free all of together once you're done worrying about the contents of this file) then sure, you can allocate lots of small strings in a more compact way. For example, put them all end to end in one or a few big allocations, each string nul-terminated, and deal in pointers to the first byte of each. The overhead is either 1 or 0 bytes per string depending how you consider the nul. This can work particularly neatly in the case of splitting a file into lines, if you just overwrite the linebreaks with nul bytes. Obviously you'd need to not mind that the linebreak has been removed from each line!

If you need freeing and re-use, and you know that *all* allocations are the same size, then you can do away with the size from the book-keeping, and write your own allocator (or, in practice, find an existing pool allocator you're happy with). The minimum allocated size could be one pointer. But that's only an easy win if *all* the strings are below the size of a pointer, "most" isn't so straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, statically-allocating a large-ish buffer and reading into that is the usual way to read data.

Say you pick 1KB for the buffer size, because you expect most reads to fit into that.

Are you able to chop rare reads that go above 1KB into multiple reads?

- Then do so.

Or not?

- Then you can dynamically allocate if and only if necessary. Some simple pointer magic will do the job.

```
static const unsigned int BUF_SIZE = 1024;
static char buf[BUF_SIZE];

while (something) {
    const unsigned int num_bytes_to_read = foo();
    const char* data = 0;

    if (num_bytes_to_read <= BUF_SIZE) {
       read_into(&buf[0]);
       data = buf;
    }
    else {
       data = new char[num_bytes_to_read];
       read_into(data);
    }

    // use data

    if (num_bytes_to_read > BUF_SIZE)
       delete[] data;
}
```

This code is a delightful mashup of C, C++ and pseudocode, since you did not specify a language.

If you're actually using C++, just use a vector for goodness' sake; let it grow if needed but otherwise just re-use its storage.

Answer (score 0):

You could count the number of lines of text and their total length first, then allocate a block of memory to store the text and a block to store pointers into it. Fill these blocks by reading the file a second time. Just remember to add terminating zeros.

Answer (score 0):

If the entire file will fit into memory, then why not get the size of the file, allocate that much memory and enough for pointers, then read in the entire file and create an array of pointers to the lines in the file?

Answer (score 0):

I would store the "x" with using the largest buffer I can.
You did not tell us what is the max size of x as sizeof(x). It is I think crucial to store it in the buffer to evade addressing for each word and access them relatively quickly.

Something like :

```
char *buffer = "word1\0word2\0word3\0";
```

while stocking addr or ...etc.. for 'quick' access

Became like this :

```
char *buffer = "xx1word1xx2word2xx3word3\0\0\0\0";
```

As you can see with an x at a fixed size it can be really effective to jump word to word without the need to store each address, only need to read x and jump incrementing the addr using x...
x is not converted in char, integer injected and read using his type size, no need the end of the string \0 for the words this way, only for the full buff to know the end of the buffer (if x==0 then its the end).

I am not that good in explaining thanks to my English I push you some code as a better explanation :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

void printword(char *buff){
    char *ptr;
    int i;
    union{
        uint16_t x;
        char c[sizeof(uint16_t)];
    }u;

    ptr=buff;
    memcpy(u.c,ptr,sizeof(uint16_t));
    while(u.x){
        ptr+=sizeof(u.x);
        for(i=0;i<u.x;i++)printf("%c",buff[i+(ptr-buff)]);/*jump in buff using x*/
        printf("\n");
        ptr+=u.x;
        memcpy(u.c,ptr,sizeof(uint16_t));
    }
}
void addword(char *buff,const char *word,uint16_t x){
    char *ptr;
    union{
        uint16_t x;
        char c[sizeof(uint16_t)];
    }u;
    ptr=buff;
/* reach end x==0 */
    memcpy(u.c,ptr,sizeof(uint16_t));
    while(u.x){ptr+=sizeof(u.x)+u.x;memcpy(u.c,ptr,sizeof(uint16_t));}/*can jump easily! word2word*/
/* */

    u.x=x;
    memcpy(ptr,u.c,sizeof(uint16_t));
    ptr+=sizeof(u.x);
    memcpy(ptr,word,u.x);
    ptr+=u.x;
    memset(ptr,0,sizeof(uint16_t));/*end of buffer x=0*/
}
int main(void){
    char buffer[1024];
    memset(buffer,0,sizeof(uint16_t));/*first x=0 because its empty*/
    addword(buffer,"test",4);
    addword(buffer,"yay",3);
    addword(buffer,"chinchin",8);
    printword(buffer);
    return 0;
}
```